# Managed Instance Group on GCP wordpress website

Tags: database, wordpress, apache, google-cloud-platform, migration

I am trying to create a **wordpress** website from a single VM to a **Managed Instance Group**.
First of all, i created a copy of all disks on VM, these disks are used to create a template for the instance group, once i created a MIG i connected a **Load Balancer** to redirect traffic between the instances.
Now i'm stuk, i can't figure out how users can connect to modify the website, i think that i have to use an SQLserver but i don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress needs MySQL or MariaDB database to store it's data in.

Unless you have your DB on another instance (not the one that runs WP) **you need to migrate it to designated DB** (in GCP or another provided) or use [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs) feature. Then point your wordpress to use this DB. Your Wordpress should be working as ususal.

**After you have your DB migrated create a template of your VM running WP.**

If you have your DB on the same machine as WP then it won't work as intended since the changes made by one user won't be reflected on another VM. It's like you'd have three identical but separate (not synchronised) WP sites.

If you have just WP engine running on your VM's in MIG then no matter which one will be accessed via the LB it will read/write data to the same single DB engine.

Have a look at the [MySQL tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql) to get better idea how to set this up.